# How to receive more answers to my already posted issue?

Tags: discussion, design

I have asked a question at an improper hour and maybe there weren't too many users online, or for any other reasons, it hasn't been viewed by too many people, and I didn't receive a proper answer to it.

I think it would be uncool to post the question again, and I don't want to do this, but how can I invite more users to read my question and share their opinion?

The link to the question is:

[Resolve conflict between two simple forms on the same web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059240/resolve-conflict-between-two-simple-forms-on-the-same-web-page/22059870)

Comment: This is most definitely NOT how you go about getting more people to look at your question.

Comment: lol, your question is quite long, and not everybody has the time to check out such a big question. Aswell you shouldnt beg for views - like this you won't get more people

Comment: I am not begging for views, my friend... I just found out that that on this community there were more people willing and knowing to help, and I tought to give it a try, thats all... True professionals who have opinions and expertise and are intrigued by such problems... Thank you anyways!

Answer (score -1):

Here are some suggestions:

- Try to explain your problem more
- Start a bounty for your question
- Promote your question on the chat (but don't spam!)